# Azure Cache ErrorCode<ERRCA0017>:SubStatus<ES0006>

Tags: c#, .net, caching, azure, azure-caching

Im trying to access MS Azure Cache service and pretty often I get this error:

```
Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException: ErrorCode<ERRCA0017>:SubStatus<ES0006>:There is a temporary failure. Please retry later. (One or more specified cache servers are unavailable, which could be caused by busy network or servers. For on-premises cache clusters, also verify the following conditions. Ensure that security permission has been granted for this client account, and check that the AppFabric Caching Service is allowed through the firewall on all cache hosts. Also the MaxBufferSize on the server must be greater than or equal to the serialized object size sent from the client.). Additional Information : The client was trying to communicate with the server: net.tcp://remoto.cache.windows.net: line 23233.
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.ThrowException(ErrStatus errStatus, Guid trackingId, Exception responseException, Byte[][] payload, EndpointID destination)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.SocketClientProtocol.Get(String key, ref DataCacheItemVersion version, ref TimeSpan timeout, ref ErrStatus err, String region, IMonitoringListener listener)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.InternalGet(String key, ref DataCacheItemVersion version, String region, IMonitoringListener listener)
   at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.<>c__DisplayClass53.<Get>b__52()
   at Infrastructure.Azure.Cache.AzureCacheServiceClient.<>c__DisplayClass6`1.<Get>b__5() in AzureCacheServiceClient.cs: line 88
   at Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.TransientFaultHandling.RetryPolicy.ExecuteAction(Func`1 func)
```

It happens when Im trying to access some object in cache like this:

```
public T Get<T>(string key)
{
    retryPolicy.ExecuteAction(() =>(T) (_cache.Get(key)));
}
```

Here is my initialization code:

```
var cacheFactory = new DataCacheFactory();
_cache = cacheFactory.GetDefaultCache();

var retryStrategy = new FixedInterval(15, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2));
_retryPolicy = new RetryPolicy<CustomCacheTransientErrorDetectionStrategy>(retryStrategy);
```

And app.config:

```
<configSections>
    <section name="dataCacheClients" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheClientsSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.Core" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
    <section name="cacheDiagnostics" type="Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureCommon.DiagnosticsConfigurationSection, Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.AzureCommon" allowLocation="true" allowDefinition="Everywhere" />
</configSections>

<dataCacheClients>
    <dataCacheClient channelOpenTimeout="1000" requestTimeout="45000" name="default">
      <autoDiscover isEnabled="true" identifier="[some.host.name]" />

      <securityProperties mode="Message" sslEnabled="true">
        <messageSecurity authorizationInfo="***" />
      </securityProperties>
    </dataCacheClient>
</dataCacheClients>
```

It happend at least three times already while the Azure Health Status (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/) said everything was fine at that time.
As the exception message says - there are some 'temporary' failures on MS side still maybe I'm doing smth wrong in my code?

Comment: have you solved this problem, as i am facing the same..

Answer (score 1):

Do you get the error a few times, and then things start working again?  If so, this is expected behavior and your application should have a policy where you retry some number of times before falling back to the persistent data store.

If you get the error consistently (more than a few seconds), it's likely the DataCacheFactory has gotten into a bad state.  You can either restart your client process, or else refresh the DataCacheFactory as described in this [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cie/archive/2014/04/29/cache-retry-fails-what-next.aspx).